# Is it possible to set the folder permissions on my local developement environment(WAMP) before uploading the files on the webserver?

Tags: php, laravel, server, wamp

Is it possible that I set the folder permission for the storage folder to 0775 on my local development environment which is WAMP before uploading the project on the webserver?

Edit: I want to set the permissions on the folder before uploading and the permission should be retained after the upload.

Comment: use chmod($target, 0775);

Comment: no. I don't think that's possible

Comment: The W in WAMP stands for Windows. Therefore permissions are rarely an issue

Answer (score -1):

Go project directory

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R bootstrap
$ sudo chmod 777 -R storage
$ sudo chmod 777 -R vendor
```

then

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data bootstrap
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data vendor
```

If you use other web server. You need change www-data to your correct user.

Comment: W in WAMP = Windows

Answer (score -1):

I think you expecting to retain the folder permission after upload. My suggestion would be to do an folder existance check in code them if not exists create and set permission for code as an dded precausion.

```
if(!is_dir('upload')){
    mkdir('upload');
    chmod('upload',0755);
}
```

Comment: W in WAMP = Windows

Comment: I understand why you wrote W in WAMP = Windows in the last comment but not sure why on my one. Can you explain how a PHP code differs based on OS platform ? I hope you read the edit portion of the original post.

Comment: On windows Apache tends to run as local system account. This rarely has issues with permissions, unless someone has done some really odd stuff to their system. Questions like this normally mean that the OP is following an UNIX setup tutorial, but does not realise the directory setup required on nix is normally not required on Windows